# How to react when the poster of a neighbouring answer updates his version with your own answer

Tags: discussion, answers, etiquette

Here is another case which came as a bit of surprise to me:

[Get ReadyState from WebBrowser control without DoEvents](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21140349/1768303)

There was initially [one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21150942/1768303) posted there, which I considered conceptually wrong, so I posted my [own version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21152965/1768303).

Soon the author of the original answer edited his version by appending mine, only with very cosmetic changes.

When I asked him in the comments about the reason for that, he had got somewhat sensitive, I think.

How should I react if thing like this happen again? Should I react at all?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate; we covered this ground before. Outright plagiarism: flag (they forgot to attribute), otherwise there isn't much you can do, really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How should I react if thing like this happen again? Should I react at all?

Yes and No.

You can flag and explain what's wrong in the flag. (Plagiarism). What else could you do really ? Other than that, there isn't much you can do. Don't get involved in a comment war over this. It will lead nowhere.

Answer (score 1):

In this specific case the best option would be to do nothing.

While it may feel a bit wrong the other answerer did give attribution to your answer as the inspiration for his/her update so plagiarism isn't really an issue here.

> I have adapted my "quick & dirty" sample by borrowing and sligthly
>   refactoring @Noseratio's NavigateAsync method from this topic.